# Using hex colors in feildset borders

Tags: html

Can I use hex colors in fieldset borders? `style="border:10px (hex here)"` If so, how?

I tried this but it didn't work. Where I wrote '(hex here)' is where colors like 'red' or 'light green' go. So my question is how could I implement hex colors into this?

Comment: Yes; but `border` is shorthand and requires `<border-width> <border-style> <border-color>`.

Comment: borders on fieldset work the same as anything else. When debugging a problem try to isolate it. So if my border wasn't showing up on fieldset I would first have tried things like adding other properties and seeing if they got applied, then changing the element to see if the border got applied. I then would see that the border didn't get applied to the other elements as well and then would have seen that I was using the incorrect syntax